# Convert sold quantity to standardized units in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a result containing total sold quantity in different units. I need to bring it to standardized units based on reference table. This standardised units can vary from KG,LBS or GAL .

Quantity Sold :

| Material | UnitOfMeasure | QuantitySold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1910 | KG | 446780 |
| 1910 | GAL | 5000 |
| 1911 | GAL | 2000 |

Reference :

| Material | FromUnits | ToUnits | Multiplier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1910 | GAL | Lbs | 7.107 |
| 1910 | Lbs | Kgs | 0.5 |
| 1910 | KG | Lbs | 2.3 |
| 1911 | GAL | Lbs | 9.3 |
| 1911 | Lbs | Kg | .9 |
| 1911 | KG | Lbs | 4.2 |

I Need :

| Material | UnitOfMeasure | QuantitySold | Standardised_Lbs | Standardised_KG | Standardised_GAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1910 | KG | 446780 | (446780*2.3) |  |  |
| 1910 | GAL | 5000 | (5000*7.1) |  |  |
| 1911 | GAL | 2000 | (2000 * 9.3) |  |  |

Comment: So what's the problem with doing that?

Comment: it also seems weird that the KG to LBS and LBS to KG are not an exact inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a `Conditional Aggregation` in concert with a `JOIN` should do the trick.

```
Select A.Material
      ,A.UnitOfMeasure
      ,A.QuantitySold
      ,Standardised_Lbs = sum( case when B.ToUnits = 'Lbs' then A.QuantitySold * B.Multiplier end )
      ,Standardised_KG  = sum( case when B.ToUnits = 'KG'  then A.QuantitySold * B.Multiplier end )
      ,Standardised_GAl = sum( case when B.ToUnits = 'GAL' then A.QuantitySold * B.Multiplier end )
 From  [QuantitySold] A
 Join  [Reference]    B on A.Material=B.Material 
                       and A.UnitOfMeasure = B.FromUnits
 Group By A.Material
         ,A.UnitOfMeasure
         ,A.QuantitySold
```

Comment: The reference table would need to be filled with all possibilities. Maybe a left join in order to find the missing references with NULL?

Comment: @KeithL A left join would do, but not necessary.   The conditional aggregation would generate NULL values if the reference table was a "miss".

Comment: Thank you for help, this should set me in correct direction.

Comment: @KeithL You are correct regarding the intersections of data   For example KG to KG would have a factor of 1.    https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b73b31f03a3301d0e5ced72380c21331